# Thymeleaf unexpected and strange class cast exception in view

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf, classcastexception

UPDATE:

*EDIT #2 below shows the temporary resolution of this issue, but raises a new question*.

I am developing a client using Spring MVC and Thymeleaf for my view.

I have two users, a basic user and an administrator. When a basic user logs in, his personal information is displayed on his home page. When an administrator logs in, he can perform various search operations to find users in a backend database (MongoDB). He can find by state, city, username, etc....

I get this error: `java.lang.ClassCastException: formBeans.User cannot be cast to java.util.Map` only after I execute a specific sequence of operations on the client:

1. log in as administrator
2. search for all users
3. log out
4. log back in as basic user
5. Above error is thrown

Like I said, when a basic user logs in, his personal info is supposed to be displayed. Logging in as a basic user works other times, but not in this specific case. However, this error might occur in other situations that I might not have run into.

Here is my User model and form backing bean class:

```
package formBeans;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class User {

    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String email;
    private String address;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String zipCode;

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }
    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }
    public String getZipCode() {
        return zipCode;
    }
    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = format(firstname);
    }
    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = format(lastname);
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = format(username);
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = format(email);
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = format(address);
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = format(city);
    }
    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = format(state);
    }
    public void setZipCode(String zipCode) {
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }

    public String format(String data) {
        String firstLetter = data.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
        String restLetters = data.substring(1).toLowerCase();
        return firstLetter + restLetters;
    }
}
```

Here is the basic user's home page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
<head>
<title>Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/topcoat-desktop-light.min.css}" href="../../css/topcoat-desktop-light.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div th:include="fragment :: header"></div>   
    <h1>Welcome, <span th:text="${credentials.username}"></span> </h1>

    <h2>My profile:</h2>
    <a th:href="@{/edit}">Edit my profile</a>
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
        <table>
            <tr><td>Firstname:</td> <td th:text="${user.firstname}"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Lastname:</td> <td th:text="${user.lastname}"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Username:</td> <td th:text="${user.username}"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Address:</td> <td th:text="${user.address}"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>City:</td> <td th:text="${user.city}"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>State:</td> <td th:text="${user.state}"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Zip code:</td> <td th:text="${user.zipCode}"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Email:</td> <td th:text="${user.email}"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Phone number:</td> <td th:text="${user.phoneNumber}"></td></tr>
            <tr><td><hr></hr></td></tr>
        </table>
</body>
</html>
```

So as you see in the html page, sometimes Thymeleaf cannot recognize the "user" object.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Thanks for the responses. Here is some more relevant code:

Stack trace: The stack trace does not give any error on a particular line number in my view or any of my Java classes. It seems like it is an internal error in the Spring's Java docs.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: formBeans.User cannot be cast to java.util.Map
    at org.springframework.context.expression.MapAccessor.read(MapAccessor.java:49)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:188)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:94)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.access$000(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:46)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference$AccessorLValue.getValue(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:375)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:88)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:120)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:267)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.expression.SpelVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SpelVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:139)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.VariableExpression.executeVariable(VariableExpression.java:154)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.SimpleExpression.executeSimple(SimpleExpression.java:59)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:103)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:133)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:120)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.attr.AbstractStandardTextChildModifierAttrProcessor.getText(AbstractStandardTextChildModifierAttrProcessor.java:68)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.attr.AbstractTextChildModifierAttrProcessor.getModifiedChildren(AbstractTextChildModifierAttrProcessor.java:59)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.attr.AbstractChildrenModifierAttrProcessor.processAttribute(AbstractChildrenModifierAttrProcessor.java:59)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.attr.AbstractAttrProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttrProcessor.java:87)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.AbstractProcessor.process(AbstractProcessor.java:212)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.applyNextProcessor(Node.java:1017)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:972)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Document.process(Document.java:93)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1155)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The "user" object is stored as a session object. Here is some relevant code from the controller:

```
   /* Here are my session attributes */
    @Controller
    @SessionAttributes({ "credentials", "user" })
    public class ViewController implements ErrorController {

    /* Here is the login function. If the user is a basic user, it redirects him to /getBasicUser.*/
        @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String login(@ModelAttribute("credentials") Credentials credentials,
                RedirectAttributes redirect) {

            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            RoleInfo roleInfo = restTemplate.postForObject(
                    "http://localhost:8080/users/login", credentials,
                    RoleInfo.class);

            if (roleInfo != null) {
                if (roleInfo.isAdmin()) {
                    return "redirect:/adminHome";
                } else {
                    redirect.addFlashAttribute("credentials", credentials);
                    return "redirect:/getBasicUser";
                }
            } else {
                return "login_fail";
            }
        }

/* This function GETs the basic user from the back-end (MongoDB) repository and stores it as a session object in the model using redirect.addFlashAttribute("user", user);*/
@RequestMapping(value = "/getBasicUser", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public <T> String getBasicUser(
            @ModelAttribute("credentials") Credentials credentials,
            Model model, RedirectAttributes redirect) {

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String url = "http://localhost:8080/users/getBasicUser?username="
                + credentials.getUsername();
        ResponseEntity<User> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(
                url,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new HttpEntity<T>(createHeaders(credentials.getUsername(),
                        credentials.getPassword())), User.class);
        User user;
        user = responseEntity.getBody();

        if (user != null) {
            redirect.addFlashAttribute("user", user);
            System.out.println("username: " + user.getUsername());
            return "redirect:/basicHome";
        } else {
            return "register_fail";
        }
    }

    /* This is the method that returns the home page. If you look at the getBasicUser() method above, it redirects it to this home page */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/basicHome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String getBasicHomePage() {
            return "basic_home";
        }
```

EDIT #2: As per https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/357, when I add `${user['firstname']}, ${user['lastname']}`, ....etc instead of `${user.firstname}, ${user.lastname}`, ...etc to my basicHome.html page, this issue no longer persists.

The original way I implemented this was using Thymeleaf Expression Language whereas the new, resolved way is Spring Expression Language. **It seems like Spring stores an object's key-value pairs as a map, and that this new way directly accesses the map's key-value pairs**. So accessing user['firstname'], would be equal to "Bob".

But now the question remains, **why can it not cast the User object into map, so that I can just access the values using ${user.key}?**

Comment: Please provide spring configuration

Comment: Also provide us the full stack trace of the error including what line number it is pointing to if it display is. We will also need to see your controller & method that is loading this view.

Comment: how is your login in system? how and where do you provide the user object so the template will always able to recognize it?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same thing when updating from thymeleaf 2 to 3.  The issue turned out to be that we had some code that used "field notation" for non-field uses.

For example, we had:

```
th:if="*{someProperty}"
```

Instead of:

```
th:if="${bean.someProperty}"
```

I had to just make this simple fix to a couple forms and we were good to go.